# Regular expression for matching numbers and having dashes as wildcards for numbers

Tags: regex

Can anyone help with this regular expression?  We store values like `1234----` and need to match that with user input.

Anything starting with `1234` and with additional numbers for each dash would be a match:

`12345678` would be a match

`123456` or `92341234` would not match

So the additional number of digits needs to be the same number as number of dashes.  And characters must be numbers, not letters or anything else.

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, either C# or VB.NET will work.  Thx.

Comment: I'll update my answer to c# in a minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So do you need to build regex from `1234----`-like string? Then you can replace each `-` with `\d`, add `^` in the beginning of the string and add `$` in the end of the string. For given string it would create `^1234\d\d\d\d$` regex.

```
string input = "12345678";
string mask = "1234----";
string regex = string.Format("^{0}$", mask.Replace("-", @"\d"));
bool isMatch = Regex.IsMatch(input, regex);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex:

```
^1234[0-9]{4}$
```

This will match all the inputs starting with `1234` followed by 4 digits.

#### [Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/qR3tB6)

Comment: Any reason you used a character group instead of `\d`?

Comment: `[0-9]` is not called a character group it is called range inside character class. I used it because OP didn't specify language used and `\d` doesn't work on many tools like sed, awk etc.

Comment: Thank you.  The number of dashes is variable, not always 4.  And the specific digits could be other numbers.  So we might need to match somthing like "43210------" or "123---456" or whatever.

Comment: But then how should it not match `123456`? Do you want to match 4 more digits?

Comment: @pseudoware As asked earlier, what's the context for this? As in, what language, and is there a chance of any surrounding code to do any further manipulation?

Comment: It's a simple form in an ASP.NET MVC app, so VB.NET or C#.  User enters their number, and we check the input against multiple possible patterns.  It only needs to match one of the patterns.

Comment: @pseudoware: You need to provide that simple pattern. In your question you provided `1234----` and that is what this answer provides. If you more requirements then edit your question.

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah, I realize my question could have been more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
^1234\d{4}$
```

Based on your comment I've updated the regex to c#:

```
matchResults = Regex.Match(subjectString, @"^1234\d{4}$");
```

***DEMO:***
http://regex101.com/r/gF2lZ0